# How to know the last job in a queue

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue

I have a group of of jobs that need to be processed.
Some may take 10 min, some may take 1h.

Now I need to know what is the last job executed because at the end of that group of jobs I need to fire another message.

The message queue in this case is RabbitMQ.

Is there a way I can accomplish this with only RabbitMQ?

What would be a good strategy for this task?

Answer (score 0):

**Thats strategy you can use with any messaging system.**

I assume you have group of workers listening to single queue with jobs "jobs queue" to be processed. Now you can have service lets call it Manager witch duplicates this queue and saves all no finished messages. Now when worker finishes the job it send acknowledgment message to the Manager. Manager for example discards all finished jobs and stores only running once. (If you want to take in to account passable failures it can track that too).
When Manager have no more messages it publishes message to the "all messages in the group done topic". Now publishers can listen to the topic and fire new job messages to the "job queue".

Of course in simple case you can have one producer witch could be the Manager in the same time.

**Example RabbitMQ implementation.**

Now to implement this in RabbitMQ you can for example create one FanoutExchange (for producer to send messages to) and two queues jobsQueue (to send jobs to workers) and jobTrackingQueue (to send jobs to Manager for tracking jobs). Now you create second FonoutExchange (for Manager to send task done messges to) you create unnamed queue per producer who wants to know if all messges are done.